# Store json response array in to session

Tags: java, android, json

My LoginActivity is sending username and password to URL and getting success status. I want to store json response like userid, name, email information in a session and retrieve it in MainActivity. I am using below code for json response.

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
String userId = jObj.getString("user_id");
```

and my response is

```
{"tag":"login",
 "error":false,
 "user_id":"5",
     "user":{"name":"Chandra shankar",
             "email":"chandra@gmail.com"
            }
}
```

below is my SharedPreferences in Session.java

```
public class Session {
    private SharedPreferences sp;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor;


    public Session(Context context) {
        sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    }


    public boolean setLogin(boolean status) {
        spEditor = sp.edit();
        spEditor.putBoolean("is_logged_in", status);
        spEditor.commit();
        return true;
    }

    public boolean getLoggedIn() {
        return sp.getBoolean("is_logged_in", false);
    }

}
```

Comment: SharedPreferences and save it as String with private access

Comment: bro i am new to android can you answer my question. also i need to print the stored data in my MainActivity.

Comment: Do you want to have auto login even when offline?

Comment: Bcoz if your doing login, you'd just store them in a JSON variable and just timeout the user once session time expired, clear the variable and they login again.. the variable can be static

Comment: yes see now my Login Activity having username and password when i enter, it will go to my index.php and get status and user data through JSON. if userid is not null i want to store user id , name , email in to session and display it in MainActivity. i am already using session to check user logged in or not if logged in it will go to mainactivity if not loginactivtiy. please see my JSON response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

```
SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("APP_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

editor.putString("ID", userId).apply();
```

if you want to get the value back.

```
String id = preferences.getString("ID");
```

EDIT

```
public class Session {
    private SharedPreferences sp;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor;
    private String ISLOGIN = "is_logged_in";
    private String USER_ID = "user_id";

    public Session(Context context) {
        sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    }


    public boolean setLogin(boolean status) {
        spEditor = sp.edit();
        spEditor.putBoolean(ISLOGIN, status);
        //use apply for async process
        spEditor.apply();
        return status;
    }

    public boolean getLoggedIn() {
        return sp.getBoolean(ISLOGIN, false);
    }

    public void setUserId(String userid){
        sp.edit().putString(USER_ID,userid).apply();
    }


    //get user id
    public String getUserId(){
       return sp.getString(USER_ID);
    }

}
```

// in activity

```
Session session = new Session(this);
String id = session.getUserId();
```

p/s: i recommended you to use this [TinyDB](https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo) SharedPreferences

Comment: ok thank you for response. please see my code i just add my SharedPreferences which i am using. where i need to add the userid as session

Answer (score 0):

So, you need two steps actually. You need to parse the response and then you need to save it .

For parsing json response , you can build a [POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527264/how-to-create-a-pojo) class. [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) will be helpful for that. You can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015844/parsing-json-object-in-java) link to parse response as well .

Then you can save the data to [Shared Preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)/ Sqlite / Local Variables / Files or any other places and use the saved value based on your need.