# The optimal way of storing data from an android list, then exporting it to sync with a master database

Tags: android, sql, database, firebase-realtime-database

I'm basically creating an android application which takes around 8 forms (forms consist of EditText field and CheckBoxes) and will store them in a database, so that it can be later synced/added to a pre-existing database (Microsoft SQL 2008).

Which would the best way to store and sync (maybe daily or weekly) data to a pre-existing database in my case. I do not have much experience in android backend, as I've only ever worked with shared preferences to store data locally, so a simpler solution will ease this process. Cheers!

Edit:

**TLDR:** This question was asked to find out, which route shall be taken when one needs to store data taken from a form filled by the user so that it can be later synced with an existing database (which in my case is a Microsoft SQL 2008). The main aim of the android application was get the various databases and push it to the cloud.

As of 24/1/17: I've created a SQLite Database and have begun storing the data, I'm still not sure which method would be the best to export the data. I will keep on documenting the progress.

Comment: you could add some examples of what you have tried or what you have to accomplish... I found this question interesting... but may lead to a discussion or a debate...

Comment: I've gone the SQLite way, as of now I'm storing the data on device by creating a database for a form. Nearly done there, I will look into then exporting the database then appending it to the main db. Just breaking all the steps into manageable chunks.

Answer (score 4):

You could look at azure cloud services [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/get-started/), you need some knowledge about odata.
or
 You could try firebase [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start), understanding of json is required.

Because you have knowledge about sql I suggest you have a look at some tutorials for linking sql with azure or sqlite with azure.

Answer (score 0):

Use a POJO and store them to firebase. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527264/how-to-create-a-pojo) and [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) or watch this [video](https://youtu.be/noB98K6A0TY). hope it helps.