# How to generate a json object using Rest web service in java

Tags: java, rest, ejb

I'm using java, i'm trying to creat a Rest web service,which can to merge a set of return json objects heres the code :

```
@Path("/all/{profileId}")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response all(@PathParam("profileId") String profileId) {
    Response profile = null;
    Response cards = null;
    Response childs= null;
    Response returnValue = null;

    try {
        ProfilJson profilJson = profilBean.getProfil(profileId);
        List<LoyaltyCardJson> listLoyaltyCardsJson = loyaltyCardBean.getcards(profileId);
        List<LoyaltyChildJson> listLoyaltyChildsJson = loyaltyCardBean.getChildd(profileId);

        if (profilJson != null) {
            profile = JsonResponse.objectToJson(profilJson);
            cards = JsonResponse.objectToJson(listLoyaltyCardsJson);    
            childs = JsonResponse.objectToJson(listLoyaltychildsJson);
        } else {
            returnValue = JsonResponse.noDataToReturn();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);

    }
    return   returnValue;
}
```

i give you an exemple of the returned objects :

> profile = [{name: "Mary", car: "Fiat"}];
>
> cards= [{firstName: "Mack", lastName: "jack"},{firstName: "Steve", lastName: "martin"}];
>
> childs= [{firstName: "toto", lastName: "jack"},{firstName: "titi", lastName: "martin"}];

what i want to do is, to generate a global object which i can put it into the returnValue variable, and this object must like :

> [{"name": "Bob", "car": "Ford",
>   "cards":[{"Name": "Mack", "Type": "jack"},{"Name": "Steve","TypeName": "martin"},...],
>   "childs":[{"firstName": "toto", "lastName": "jack"},{"firstName": "titi", "lastName": "martin"},...]
>   }]

P.S
cards and childs objects contain a list of objects, i gave two objects to each one in this exemple just help you to understand the problem.

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Comment: what is this ??

Comment: I'm going to have to tell you the same thing i told you on your other post, create a POJO then parse to JSON.

Comment: Actually you can generate a POJO to contain your names and cards and childs arrays, name that POJO as ReturnValue. You are done.

Comment: could you provide an exemple pleaes ?

Comment: @newme here you have examples and a explanation of what's POJO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527264/how-to-create-a-pojo

Comment: if i create a POJO which contain all the fields, how can i use it in the web service ?