# Update the existing Yaml file

Tags: java, jackson, yaml, jackson-databind

I want to update my existing `user.yaml` file without erasing other objects or properties.

I have been googling for 2 days for a solution, but with no luck.

**Actual Output:**

```
name: Test User
age: 30
address:
  line1: My Address Line 1
  line2: Address line 2
  city: Washington D.C.
  zip: 20000
roles:
  - User
  - Editor
```

**Expected Output**

```
name: Test User
age: 30
address:
  line1: Your address line 1
  line2: Your Address line 2
  city: Bangalore
  zip: 560010
roles:
  - User
  - Editor
```

The above is my yaml file. I want to fetch this yaml file and update the address of the object and write the same information to the new yaml file / existing yaml file. This has to be done without harming other objects (i.e other objects key and values should be retained).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need [`YAMLMapper`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-yaml/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/yaml/YAMLMapper.html) (from [`jackson-databind-yaml`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml))
which is the YAML-specific implementation of [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) (from [`jackson-databind`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind)).

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new YAMLMapper();
```

Then it is easy: just read the YAML file, modify the contents, and write the YAML file.

Because you have a very simple object structure in your example,
you may prefer a quick-and-dirty modeling by using `Map<String, Object>`.

```
// read YAML file
Map<String, Object> user = objectMapper.readValue(new File("user.yaml"),
            new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() { });
    
// modify the address
Map<String, Object> address = (Map<String, Object>) user.get("address");
address.put("line1", "Your address line 1");
address.put("line2", "Your address line 2");
address.put("city", "Bangalore");
address.put("zip", 560010);
    
// write YAML file
objectMapper.writeValue(new File("user-modified.yaml"), user);
```

If you would have a more complex object structure,
then you should do a more object-oriented modeling
by writing some [POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527264/how-to-create-a-pojo) classes (`User` and `Address`).
But the general idea is still the same:

```
// read YAML file
User user = objectMapper.readValue(new File("user.yaml"), User.class);
    
// modify the address
Address address = user.getAddress();
address.setLine1("Your address line 1");
address.setLine2("Your address line 2");
address.setCity("Bangalore");
address.setZip(560010);
    
// write YAML file
objectMapper.writeValue(new File("user-modified.yaml"), user);
```

Comment: Thanks, its working :) . actually I did a lot of research, next time will try to give more information so my question doesn't get down voted :P.  quick one: do snakeyaml supports annotation to read properties from .yaml file like jackson  do `@JsonProperty("user-report")`