# Create an object in java and assign items

Tags: java, object

In `Javascript` one could create an object like:

```
       newdata: {
            zero_to_one: {self: 0, bulk: 0, norm: 0},
            one_to_2: {self: 0, bulk: 0, norm: 0},
            two_to_4: {self: 0, bulk: 0, norm: 0},
            over_four: {self: 0, bulk: 0, norm: 0},
        }
```

Modifying the data in javascript is simple by just calling `this.zero_to_one.self =2`

How can i achieve the same in java

Comment: Create a Java POJO, then use the mutator methods or set fields directly.  Have you tried anything?  This is a pretty basic thing to do in Java.

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527264/how-to-create-a-pojo

Comment: Please start from reading some basic literature about Java syntax, that will initially boost you up and save you plenty of time.

Comment: Better start by learning some basic syntax as everyone suggested. It's not like transitioning between java and kotlin and not expected to be very intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Declaration and creation of an object in Java

## SHORT VERSION

The conversion of JS to Java would be as follows:

#### `JS`

```js
newdata: {
            zero_to_one: {self: 0, bulk: 0, norm: 0},
            one_to_2: {self: 0, bulk: 0, norm: 0},
            two_to_4: {self: 0, bulk: 0, norm: 0},
            over_four: {self: 0, bulk: 0, norm: 0},
}
```

#### `JAVA`

```java
// ZeroToOne.java
public class ZeroToOne {

    int self; // Type self
    int bulk; // Type bulk
    int norm; // Type norm

    /**
     * GETTERS AND SETTERS
     */

    public int getSelf() {
        return self;
    }

    public void setSelf(int self) {
        this.self = self;
    }

    public int getBulk() {
        return bulk;
    }

    public void setBulk(int bulk) {
        this.bulk = bulk;
    }

    public int getNorm() {
        return norm;
    }

    public void setNorm(int norm) {
        this.norm = norm;
    }

}
```

In the same way you will be able to do it with `one_to_2`,`two_to_4` and `over_four`.

This is called a **simple object creation** and is what we **call `POJO` in java**.

> ℹ️ More information:
>   [Plain_old_Java_object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object)

## LARGE VERSION

Following the previous example:

```java
   public class ZeroToOne {

    // Attributes of the ZeroToOne class
    private int self; // Type self
    private int bulk; // Type bulk
    private int norm; // Type norm

    // Methods of the ZeroToOne class

    /**
     * GETTERS AND SETTERS
     */
    public int getSelf() {
        return self;
    }

    public void setSelf(int s) {
        this.self = s;
    }

    public int getBulk() {
        return bulk;
    }

    public void setBulk(int b) {
        this.bulk = b;
    }

    public int getNorm() {
        return norm;
    }

    public void setNorm(int norm) {
        this.norm = norm;
    }
}
```

Note that, in the **class body**, *between the `{}`* keys have been defined:

- Three `attributes` (also called `private fields`): `self`,`bulk` and `norm`.
- Six public methods (`public`): `getSelf`, `setSelf`,`getBulk`, `setBulk`,`getNorm` and `setNorm`.

In such a way that all the objects that are created from the `ZeroToOne` class will have a `self`, `bulk` and `norm` that will be able to store different values, being able to be modified or consulted when their defined methods are invoked :

- `setSelf`/`setBulk`/`setNorm` ⇨ **allows you to ASSIGN *set* to `self` / `bulk` / `norm` (int) to an object of the`ZeroToOne`** class.
- `getSelf`/`getBulk`/`getNorm` ⇨ **allows you to CONSULT *get* the `self` / `bulk` / `norm` of an object of the`ZeroToOne` class**.

To **declare and create an object of class `ZeroToOne`**:

```java
    ZeroToOne callZeroToOne; // Declaration of variable p1 of type Person
    ZeroToOne zOne = new ZeroToOne (); // Create an object of the Person class
```

In addition, the same can be indicated in a single line:

```
ZeroToOne callZeroToOne = new ZeroToOne();
```

---

### Modify the value

And where to directly modify the value of `self` you will have to do it in the following way:

```
    ZeroToOne callZeroToOne; // Declaration of variable p1 of type Person
    ZeroToOne zOne = new ZeroToOne (); // Create an object of the Person class
    zOne.setSelf (2); // We modify the value
    System.out.println (zOne.getSelf ()); // Impression of the result
```

What we would get

```
> 2
```

Comment: If easy instantiation is important, one could also add a constructor taking name and age as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

```
newdata: {
            zero_to_one: {self: 0, bulk: 0, norm: 0},
            one_to_2: {self: 0, bulk: 0, norm: 0},
            two_to_4: {self: 0, bulk: 0, norm: 0},
            over_four: {self: 0, bulk: 0, norm: 0},
}
```

If you look at the structure ,
it is Object within a Object .
So what you can do is to create 4 child object zero_to_one,
one_to_2,two_to_4,over_four .

All four child object has the same three field self,bulk,norm.
You can also fit all four into one if you want.

A simple Object creation , what we call POJO in java requires the following :

```
public class ZeroToOne{
        String self;
        String bulk;
        String norm;

        public String getSelf() {
            return self;
        }

        public void setSelf(String self) {
            this.self= self;
        }

        public String getBulk() {
            return bulk;
        }

        public void setBulk(String bulk) {
            this.bulk = bulk;
        }

        public String getNorm() {
            return norm;
        }

        public void setNorm(String norm) {
            this.norm = norm;
        }

    }
```

After that you can get and set value using those getter/setter method.