# How to set and get a String value from constructor using method in Java?

Tags: java

My goal is to return a value from local variable that I need to set first by calling a method. It could sound dumb, sorry, I do not have much practice with java yet, tried googling for 2 hours and haven't found the solution.

Step by step goal:

1. Create local String variable in constructor
2. Set its value
3. Create method that will return this value

This is what I got yet:

```
public class TestString{

    public TestString(){

    }

    public String name;

    public TestString (String name){
        this.name=name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Comment: naming conventions aside, what is not working?

Comment: OK, what is the problem with what you have? The empty constructor is not necessary, but other than that?

Comment: Can you tell me what is expected?  the toString method seems to do the job.  If you want to prevent instantiating TestString without a string, then remove the default constructor.

Comment: your option is 100% correct. You can also call the default constructor (no need to create one), and implement a "setName(String name)" method.

Comment: I'm not sure if I wrote the right code :D

Comment: One thing, though. This variable is an **instance** variable. It's not a local variable. There is no way to access a local variable from outside the scope where it is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called a POJO: read further [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3527340/6090738)

```
public class TestString {

private String name;

public TestString(String name) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
}

public TestString() {
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "TestString [name=" + name + "]";
}

}
```

> your Goals

Step by step goal:

1. Pass a String variable in a constructor

   `TestString testString = new TestString("this is a test string");`
2. Set its value (not from the constructor) - **setters**

   `testString.setName("this is a new test string");`
3. return variable value - **getters**

   `String res = testString.getName();`

Comment: Many thanks! This is just I needed.

Comment: I've edited my answer to give you a gist about getters and setters in a POJO. Accept it if you found it helpful.

Comment: Yay! Thank you, you have helped to make it more clear for me